# How to create a Server using ServerSocket to connect two or more client device via wifi

Tags: java, android, server, serversocket

Am trying to connect (using ServerSocket for server) to android device via wifi. But the problems seems to be the ip of the server. what ip can i use, or is there some other way round.

**-Code Sample**

```
//ServerSide
WifiManager wmanager = (WifiManager)context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String addr = String.valueOf(wmanager.getConnectionInfo().getIpAddress());
ServerSocket server = ServerSocket(3000, 3, InetAddress.getByName(addr));
Socket s = server.accept();

//ClientSide
//Howerver testing with terminal<telnet: open wifiIp 3000> returns connection error.
```

Comment: If you want your server to listen on port 3000 then `ServerSocket server = ServerSocket(3000);` will do. The server does not need to know ip's. It's on the client side that the client needs to know the ip of the server in order to connect.

Comment: You are trying to connect the wifi devices to the `ServerSocket`, you mean.

Comment: @EJP Yes i am.  Having issue on which IpAddress the server will lie on.. Used localhost but still won't work

Comment: You can only use localhost if server and client are on the same device. Are they?

Comment: @greenapps. No, they are on different device. Gotten it already, used ip 192.168.43.1 for the server